# How to get Excel VBA to Create and Fill in Data if Needed

Tags: excel, vba, automation, data-cleaning

1) Write a statement in excel that will insert rows and fill missing data for days missing any hour. Hours in “DATE_HR” should go from 00-23 (24 hour time).

And

2) For hours that are listed, under “DATE_HR” (DD-MMM-YYYY-HH), that are missing “0” (which is NDG in “Class”) “1-4”, “GR”, and/or “SB” in “CLASSIFICATION”, for any given hour, write a statement that will insert and fill missing rows in all hours that has the missing “CLASSIFICATION”, “Class”, “DATE_HR”, AND “Total” (which missing “TOTAL” row values should be zero since there was no entry for the missing data).

Below is an example of what the program needs to do. The left is the missing data table (before) and the right is the corrected table (after), Yellow is 1 and blue is 2

[image: Data Table example]

-Here is my progress up to now:

I have written pseudo code for the issue and have started writing at in excel VBA. Here is the pseudo code:

```
SR = Selected_row
RA = Row_above
C = Classification
DT = Date & Time
IR=Insert_row
# = Any number 1-4

Start on seleted row

Loop statement:
= IF(SRC = ”GR” AND RAC = 4 AND SRDT== RADT, SR,
OR(SRC = ”SB” AND RAC = “GR” AND SRDT== RADT, SR,
OR(SRC = 0 AND RAC = “SB” AND SRDT== RADT -1day/+22hour, SR,
OR(SRC = # AND RAC = SRC -1 AND SRDT == RADT, SR,
OR(SRC = 0 AND RADT = -1day of SRC/23hour, SRC = “0” AND SRDT= RADT +1day/00hour,IR AND
IF(RAC = ”SB” AND RADT = 23hour, SRC = “0” AND SRDT= RADT +1day/00hour,
OR (RAC = ”SB”, SRC = “0” AND SRDT= RADT +1hour,
OR (RAC = ”GR”, SRC = “SB” AND SRDT= RADT,
OR (RAC = 4, SRC = “GR” AND SRDT= RADT,
OR(RAC = # AND SRC = RAC +1 AND SRDT == RADT, SR         *here # = 0-3
)))))))))))))
Move onto next row below previous row
IF(SR=””, END program, continue)
```

Here is the excel VBA code: (the colors are just it see if it’s doing what it should)

Sub IF_Loop()

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 155
    If (Range("B" & i).Value = "GR" And Range("B" & i - 1).Value = 4 And Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i - 1).Value) Or _
    (Range("B" & i).Value = "SB" And Range("B" & i - 1).Value = "GR" And Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i - 1).Value) Or _
    (Range("B" & i).Value = "4" And Range("B" & i - 1).Value = "3" And Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i - 1).Value) Or _
    (Range("B" & i).Value = "3" And Range("B" & i - 1).Value = "2" And Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i - 1).Value) Or _
    (Range("B" & i).Value = "2" And Range("B" & i - 1).Value = "1" And Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i - 1).Value) Or _
    (Range("B" & i).Value = "1" And Range("B" & i - 1).Value = "00" And Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i - 1).Value) Then
        Rows(i & ":" & i).Interior.Color = 9359529
    Else
        'insert row and correct data
        Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.Insert shift:=x1Down And _
        Rows(i & ":" & i)
    End If
Next i
```

I’m not sure how to write the remaining code. How do you properly write the remaining lines so the code will execute the tasks that are needed?

Comment: Is DATE_HR an actual formatted date, or text?

Comment: It is information extracted from Oracle SQL. I think it might be text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this differently.

You need to know your starting and ending dates, and you also need to have a list of ALL of the Classifications and the associated Classes.  (I hard coded both within the macro, but you can use other schemes).

From that you can create a table with all of the classes and all of the hours for all of the dates.

Once you've done that, you can look up to see if the Totals are available for the classification/date combination, and either write that in, or, if not present, a zero.

I used a class object which contains the information.  Each of these objects has a collection (dictionary) of all the date_hr | total combinations available for that classification, and also a method to return the class for a given classification.

Working with VBA arrays is orders of magnitude faster than multiple read/writes to/from worksheets.

I hopefully have commented the code enough so you can understand what is going on.
For an excellent discussion of class objects, see the late Chip Pearsons [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx). *If this link dies, you'll need to do a web search*.  There is also an article there on reading/writing arrays to/from worksheet ranges which you will find useful.

Read the comments, especially at the beginning of each module, carefully so as to properly set things up, otherwise, it won't run.

It does assume that your data has a header row, and starts in `A1`.

The results are placed on the same worksheet, but it should be obvious how to change that.

### Class Module

```
'**Rename this module: cClass**
Option Explicit
Private pClass As String
Private pClassification As String
Private pDate_HR As Date
Private pDate_HRs As Dictionary

Public Property Get class() As String
    Select Case Me.Classification
    Case "1"
        class = "Freshman"
    Case "2"
        class = "Sophomore"
    Case "3"
        class = "Junior"
    Case "4"
        class = "Senior"
    Case "GR"
        class = "Graduate"
    Case "SB"
        class = "Second Bachelor"
    Case "0"
        class = "NDG"
    Case Else
        class = "N/A"
End Select
End Property


Public Property Get Classification() As String
    Classification = pClassification
End Property
Public Property Let Classification(Value As String)
    pClassification = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Date_HR() As Date
    Date_HR = pDate_HR
End Property
Public Property Let Date_HR(Value As Date)
    pDate_HR = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Date_HRs() As Dictionary
    Set Date_HRs = pDate_HRs
End Property
Public Function addDate_HRsItem(dtHR As Date, toTAL As Long)
        Date_HRs.Add Key:=dtHR, Item:=toTAL
End Function


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pDate_HRs = New Dictionary
        pDate_HRs.CompareMode = TextCompare
End Sub
```

### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
'set reference to microsoft scripting runtime

Sub fillData()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim dD As Dictionary, cc As cClass
    Dim sKey As String, sDTkey As Date

'set source and results worksheets, range
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 7)

'read source data into vba array
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=4)
End With

'Process the known data
'collect it into a dictionary for fast lookups
Set dD = New Dictionary
    dD.CompareMode = TextCompare
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set cc = New cClass
    With cc
        .Classification = vSrc(I, 1)
        .Date_HR = convDTHR(vSrc(I, 3))
        .addDate_HRsItem .Date_HR, CLng(vSrc(I, 4))
        sKey = .class

        If Not dD.Exists(sKey) Then
            dD.Add sKey, cc
        Else
            dD(sKey).addDate_HRsItem .Date_HR, CLng(vSrc(I, 4))
        End If
    End With
Next I

'Create Results Array
'Unclear from your question how many dates you want, so will
'  just do Mar 4

Const dtStart As Date = #3/4/2019#
Const dtEnd As Date = #3/5/2019#

'code the list of all Classifications
Dim arrClass
    arrClass = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, "GR", "SB")
ReDim vRes(0 To (dtEnd - dtStart + 1) * 24 * (UBound(arrClass) + 1), 1 To 4)

'write the column Headers into a results array
For J = 1 To 4
    vRes(0, J) = vSrc(1, J)
Next J

'fill in other columns
For I = 1 To UBound(vRes, 1) Step UBound(arrClass) + 1
    For J = 0 To UBound(arrClass)
        vRes(I + J, 1) = arrClass(J) 'Classification
        vRes(I + J, 2) = convCLASS(arrClass(J)) 'class
        vRes(I + J, 3) = Format(dtStart + Int((I + J - 1) / (UBound(arrClass) + 1)) / 24, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh") 'The Date_hr
        sKey = vRes(I + J, 2) 'key into dictionary
        If dD.Exists(sKey) Then
            sDTkey = convDTHR(vRes(I + J, 3)) 'key into collection of date/totals within the dictionary item
            If dD(sKey).Date_HRs.Exists(sDTkey) Then
                vRes(I + J, 4) = dD(sKey).Date_HRs(sDTkey)
            Else
                vRes(I + J, 4) = 0
            End If
        Else
            vRes(I + J, 4) = 0
        End If
    Next J
Next I

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Columns(1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub

Private Function convDTHR(strDTHR) As Date
    convDTHR = CDate(Left(strDTHR, 11)) + Right(strDTHR, 2) / 24
End Function

Private Function convCLASS(strClassification) As String
    Dim cc As cClass
Set cc = New cClass
With cc
    .Classification = strClassification
    convCLASS = .class
End With
End Function
```

Comment: I'll let you know how it goes today.